# How to convert a string-type Dictionary in a list into Dictionary

Tags: python

The following codes will return to a string which is actually a series of dictionary in a list.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()
headers = {'User-Agent': ua.random}
    
response = requests.get('https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/historical-market-capitalization/AAPL?limit=5&apikey=dd06415919d31913455307c546a9ea28', headers = headers)
content = response.content
parser = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
parser_text = parser.text
```

The returned value of parser_text is

[ {
"symbol" : "AAPL",
"date" : "2021-04-30",
"marketCap" : 2225506979220
}, {
"symbol" : "AAPL",
"date" : "2021-04-29",
"marketCap" : 2259703876360
}, {
"symbol" : "AAPL",
"date" : "2021-04-28",
"marketCap" : 2286046443040
}, {
"symbol" : "AAPL",
"date" : "2021-04-27",
"marketCap" : 2299908530320
}, {
"symbol" : "AAPL",
"date" : "2021-04-26",
"marketCap" : 2305556047360
} ]

How can I convert parser_text into a list containing each dictionary as elements like

[ '{ "symbol" : "AAPL", "date" : "2021-04-30", "marketCap" : 2225506979220 }', '{ "symbol" : "AAPL", "date" : "2021-04-29", "marketCap" : 2259703876360 }', '{ "symbol" : "AAPL", "date" : "2021-04-28", "marketCap" : 2286046443040 }', '{ "symbol" : "AAPL", "date" : "2021-04-27", "marketCap" : 2299908530320 }', '{ "symbol" : "AAPL", "date" : "2021-04-26", "marketCap" : 2305556047360 }' ]

Comment: BeautifulSoup is for parsing HTML data. It looks like your response is JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **json.loads**

```
import json
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()
headers = {'User-Agent': ua.random}
    
response = requests.get('https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/historical-market-capitalization/AAPL?limit=5&apikey=dd06415919d31913455307c546a9ea28', headers = headers)
content = response.content
parser_text = json.loads(content)
```

Comment: whats the use of bs4 here?

Comment: he can do that directely with request

Answer (score 2):

We can parse the response json using request library itself

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get("https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/historical-market-capitalization/AAPL?limit=5&apikey=dd06415919d31913455307c546a9ea28")
return_dict = response.json()
print(return_dict)
```

I don't see the use case of BeautifulSoup or any other external parser here.